# How to transform yaml config file as part of Azure DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to make Azure DevOps Release pipeline which will take some yaml config file from artifact, then set fields in this file from variables and finally deploy transformed file to target machine.

Currently I'm having trouble with setting fields in yaml file - can't find task for this.
Standard [FileTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/file-transform-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task can't handle YAML files.

[Magic Chunks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks) extension task is handling yaml files and doing substitution correctly, but it works only on Windows, and some of my target machines are Linux. Also Magic Chunks strips all comments when modifying file - еhis behavior is very inconvenient as source yaml file has lots of useful comments.

So what task (or tool) can be used to set data in yaml files inside Azure DevOps Release pipeline? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What type of YAML configuration file? Transforming config files is not necessarily the best approach depending on the platform you're trying to configure.

Comment: It's Filebeat configuration file. I need to set some custom fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/). You're probably familiar with jq for manipulating json files and yq is performing the same task for yaml files.

There is no Azure DevOps task wrapper for it, so I'd call it from a straight shell task. It works on both linux and windows, so you shouldn't have any problems.